# App is live but InApp Purchase is not submitted

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My app is currently live. During the submission i didn't checked the inapp purchases and didn't submitted for review. Now the app is live but i am unable to submit the inapp purchases the but button is disabled. How to submit the inapp purchases again without reuploading new version.
Can any one please help me in this. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this. You would need to submit app again and include that in-app purchase with it.

You can also try and send an email to Apple support, but I think by the time you get any resolution on that - regular way (re-submitting the app) would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to re-submit application.

**Please make sure you select the In-App purchase from your application version detail page other wise you will again face the same issue.**